# How to add native android code to LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, libgdx

I want to write native code for my Android app. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/) to add CPP files to my project. It compiles, but it conflicts with LibGDX.

How can I combine this with LibGDX?

I want to know how to add a simple CPP file with one function which will be called from my Android game.

I am using Android Studio.

When I add jni path to my Android gradle, LibGDX stops working:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = 'cppsrc'
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

Comment: You use interfaces and implement 'em on the launcher, you say it conflicts with libgdx? how? there's no reason that would happen, can you show us any log???

Comment: @Hllink It gives this error `Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit`

Comment: libgdx.so is not getting copied to any of the armeabi, armeabi-v7a or x86 folders in the android project's lib folder. Copy those files and then call on your project static { System.loadLibrary("gdx");}, if you dont want to do it by hand follow this link so android studio gonna pack  your apk right: http://imgur.com/a/IBFIV

Comment: @Hllink I updated my question. Either LibGDX is working or my native code

Comment: Try to put **libGDX.so** in a different directory, e.g. *libgdx/armeabi* and *libgdx/armeabi-v7a* and in **build.gradle** change `jniLib.srcDirs=['libs','libgdx']`

Comment: yes, when you use the NDK instead SDK it resolves the dependencies different, just do what we say.

Comment: I am trying this now. Another thing is that when I remove `jni.srcDirs = 'cppsrc'`, LibGDX works fine, but now my C++ code.

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe I should create my own shared library?

Comment: I had similar problem - it was either libgdx, either my custom lib. Followed @AlexCohn advice - added both of them to jniLib.srcDirs=['libs','libs-libgdx']. But also I had to change that copyAndroidNatives task in gradle file (which was generated by libgdx tool) - change all paths like libs/armeabi/ to libs-libgdx/armeabi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried jnigen? jnigen is a small library that can be used with or without libgdx which allows C/C++ code to be written inline with Java source code. Read this please from LibGDX site [JNIGEN](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/jnigen)

Answer (score 0):

When you generate LibGDX project, there are some separate project directory. Core, Desktop, Android, IOS, HTML.
You can add Android code in Android project directory, using java obviously. I have done it, and it can be easly done. It just like writing Android program with LibGDX game class as its view.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not answer my question.